# Arquivo php.ini, 'reseta configurações' durante start do apache

Tags: apache

Estou enfrentando uma falha com o UwAmp. Sempre que altero configurações no arquivo PHP.INI e reinicio o UwAmp, as configurações voltam para default. No Xampp ou no VampServer, o problema não ocorre.

Aparece a seguinte mensagem;

> "This file has been modified by another program. Do you want to reload it?"

Alguém já passou por esse problema?

Comment: Me parece que o problema é o editor, segue uma solução https://superuser.com/questions/206226/how-to-stop-warning-in-notepad-if-file-has-been-modified-from-outside

Comment: @FelipeDuarte Duarte, obrigado por responder!
Então, modifiquei as propriedades do editor, e mesmo assim sempre que inicio o apache (no **UwAmp**). redefine as configurações.
Já no XAMPP, funciona perfeitamente.

Comment: realmente nunca vi nada parecido, a propósito, se o xampp funciona não vejo necessidade do Wamp

Comment: Sim, concordo contigo.
Mas o cliente utiliza esse UwAmp hahahahaha.
Convenci ele à utilizar o xampp.
Porém, gostaria mesmo de descobrir o motivo desse erro.
Bom, caso eu descubra aqui, posto a solução.
Muito obrigado Felipe Duarte.